# nested horizontalPager Sliding not smooth

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, jetpack-compose-accompanist

i hava a nested HorizontalPager like this:

```
HorizontalPager(
   count = list.size
) {
   HorizontalPager(
    count = list2.size
   ) {
     //items
   }
 }
```

when i slide the page in the outPager border ,it seem like the inner pager block slide.
[block the slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k00T5.png)

i try to use ，but not work

```
object : NestedScrollConnection {
                    override fun onPreScroll(
                        available: Offset,
                        source: NestedScrollSource
                    ): Offset {

                        if (source == NestedScrollSource.Drag && available.x != 0f) {
                            return Offset(available.x, y = 0f)
                        }
                        return Offset.Zero

                    }
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472211/nested-horizontalpager-sliding-not-smooth  i also take a questions